# Android APk is not visible in google play

Tags: android, performance, apk

I am first time uploading apk to google play, In my manifest i declared min sdk is 14 and targeted version is  17. But when i search my apk from version 4.0.3 its not visible. But same app will visible from other devices. Can anyone guide me on why this will happen.

Comment: Did you add something about supported screen resolutions in your manifest?

Comment: yes, but set all for true even includes of xlarge.

Comment: Can you show the manifest ? And what is the model of your test device ?

Comment: did your application contains features that is not available in your device? e.g your application offers telephony features and your device is a tablet with no telephony operations available

Answer (score 1):

Try to install app from the web browser under your phone's google account. It will show you the reason, why the application cannot be installed.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google Play developer support there might be few reasons due to which app can not be found when searching by its name.

In general, when a Google Play user searches or browses android app in the Google Play store, results are filtered based on a number of elements.

First, the manifest file and the device's hardware and features are part of how applications are filtered. In addition, filtering also depends on the country and mobile carrier, the presence or absence of a SIM card, and other factors. For example, if an application requires the telephony feature (as specified in the manifest file), then Google Play will not show your app on any device that does not support it, which is majority of tablets.

Set hardware requirement as false if you are using any.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:required="false" >
```

check this for more info.. http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html